# INSERTしたいけど、できない。(PDO)

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

> 7/24 14:55 追記(1)
> $pdo->prepareではなく$dbh->prepareにし、INSERTの後にINTOを記入したら、下記のように表示されました。
>
> 接続しました。ERROR:SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database
> selected

php.pdoというファイルを作り、localhost/php.pdoでアクセスすると「接続しました」とだけ表示されます。phpmyadminにデータを挿入したいのですが、現段階で何が足りていないのでしょうか。personlというデータベースのfriendというテーブルにデータを挿入したいです。ご教示のほど宜しくお願いします。

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_NAME', 'personal');
     
// エラー表示設定:通知系以外全て表示    
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
     
try {
         
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:'.DB_NAME.';'.DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
print('接続しました。');
>             
//SQL文を作る(新規レコード追加)
 $sql = "INSERT friend(name,price) VALUES
(‘フライドポテト’,100),
('タコス’,200),
(‘フライドチキン’,300)";
//プリペアドステートメントを作る
$stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
//SQL文を実行
$stm->execute();           
}
catch(PDOException $e){
print('ERROR:'.$e->getMessage());
exit;
}
?>
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: マルチポスト - https://teratail.com/questions/137555

Comment: teratail含め複数のサイトでマルチポストを繰り返されていますが、teratailではヘルプにも注意書きがあるようなので参照してみてください。 StackOverflowでも特に禁止にはなっていませんが、回答してくれる人の事も考えて予め質問文に明記してもらえると印象が違うと思います。 - [teratail | ヘルプ](https://teratail.com/help#posted-otherservice)

Comment: わかりました。以後マルチポストは気をつけます。

Answer (score 2):

`print`のあとに不要な文字列が入っているためそこで止まっているのではないでしょうか？

```
print('接続しました。');
>
```

おそらくPHPエラーが出力されないようになっていると思われるため、[`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.error-reporting.php)をファイル先頭に追加してエラーを表示するようにすればエラーが出るかと思います。

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); // 全てのエラーを表示する
```